# Where can I find replacement handles for windows from 1956?

Tags: windows

I have 22 windows in my old house and they all need new handles/openers before I can move out in one month.  Can only find a name in a scroll font on the inside of the pane, but I cannot read it. Does anyone know who used an old scroll font for putting in the name of the company who built the window? Gotta then find the handles.

Comment: You could find these from manufacturer but I doubt it.  You need to post pictures and measurements.  You will most likely be buying a general reproduction and hoping they fit - if they don't making them fit.  What did you do with the old handles?  And why are the handles needed before you move out?

Comment: Yeah, clear photos of the company name, the window handle area (up close), and the window as a whole are needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Try Restoration Hardware. Click on Residential Catalog, then Hardware, then Windows.